# Python library to obtain atomic orbitals of atoms in the lowest energy state

Tags: python, software-recommendations, electronic-structure, one-topic-per-answer, atomistic-simulation

I want to code an UHF code. Hence for each atom I need the lowest energy electronic configuration. Is there a python package/library that already does it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Mendeleev

You can use a python library called Mendeleev. Below is an example of a Silicon atom.

```
from mendeleev import element
si = element('Si')
print(si.econf)

>> '[Ne] 3s2 3p2'
```